# How to create dependent dropdown in drupal 7 content type?

Tags: drupal, content-type

I have created two custom content type in drupal 7. One is `tourname` and another one is `location`. 
I added a tour name in tour content type like tour1,tour2 and so on. And location content type as location1, location 2 and so on for each tour name.

Now I created third content type and named it as `details` in that I need two drop down one being list of tours I have added and another one is list of locations I have inserted. Whenever I changed the tour drop down value, the second drop down value will get automatically updated based on the tour name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax Chain Select may help for making dependent hierarchical dropdowns. This helps making a series of dropdowns where the options in next dropdown are dependent of previous dropdown selection. on selecting any value, an ajax hit is made to the server that fills up the next dropdown with the intended options.

https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_chain_select

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal's built-in Ajax functionality on your details_node_form

The documentation is here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7